# AND operator is not working in while loop - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

this python script supposed to shut down a computer at the desired time, but the problem is that on the 9th line if 'hour' is equal to the current hour than the program doesn't look at the minutes. What should I add or change?
Thanks.

```
import subprocess
import datetime as dt
import time

hour = dt.datetime.now().hour
minute = dt.datetime.now().minute
print("Your computer is about to get shutdowned")

while hour != 23 and minute != 28:
    time.sleep(2)
    print("not yet!")

subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/s"])
```

Comment: You never update `hour` or `minute`.

Comment: You want `while not (hour == 23 and minute == 28)` as your condition, and you also need to update those variables inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `user2357112` said, you set `hour` and `minute` when you start the program, but never updates it again.

This should work:

```
while hour != 23 and minute != 28:
    print("not yet!")
    time.sleep(50)
    hour = dt.datetime.now().hour
    minute = dt.datetime.now().minute

print("Your computer is about to get shutdowned")
subprocess.call(["shutdown", "/s"])
```

And you don't need to check every 2 seconds if it's time to shutdown. Twice a minute is enough.

Comment: Thank you very much! now everything works properly :)

Answer (score 0):

You should get hour and minutes inside the loop other way you get just one value for each when you start your script and values are never update...

try something like :

```
while hour != 23 and minute != 28:
    hour = dt.datetime.now().hour
    minute = dt.datetime.now().minute
    time.sleep(2)
    print("not yet!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 'and' to 'or'. Also you have to update hour and minute inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to calculate the next due date at 23:28:

```
import datetime
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now()
due_date = now.replace(hour=23, minute=28)
if due_date < now:
    due_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Then, you can do your countdown:

```
print("Your computer is about to get shutdowned...")
while datetime.datetime.now() < due_date:
    time.sleep(2)
    duration = due_date - datetime.datetime.now()
    print("... in {:d} seconds".format(int(duration.seconds)))
```